# Virtualsize and alignment PE sections

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

Hi I would like to understand why should I align my section's Virtualsize to 0x1000 (4096 dec) and there are other section's who uses less Virtualsize space that isn't aligned at all to SectionAlignment and still works fine.
[image]

that's an example of what am talking about am basically doing this:

```
unsigned int align_to_boundary(unsigned int address, unsigned int boundary) {
return (((address + boundary - 1) / boundary) * boundary);}
```

and passing for example 0x30a as address aka size of my code and SectionAlignment as boundary param.

could I just pass any value to virtual size that isn't aligned?

Comment: “address aka size” Uh no. Address and size are completely different things.

Comment: @nobody but both of them need to be aligned by Section alignment & file alignment. So it doesn't matter it just a function that calculates the multiple of a given number.

Answer (score 0):

turns out after searching that VirtualSize member doesn't need to be aligned since the loader will map and align it to a page size which is exactly what section Alignment is all about. So no need to align it when the loader is going to do it anyway.